# Silly joke about Yoneda, but is it that silly..?

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

I stated this as a joke, but if you think about it, could this not be true in some sense..? This is the joke:

**"Does the Yoneda Lemma have the universal property of being the unique result in category theory through which every well-defined statement factors?"**

I'm still very much a beginner in CT, and have but a vague understanding of what the lemma says, but given the gravitas it is assigned by category theorists, as well as the nature of the statement itself (namely that it 'extrinsically determines all intrinsic properties of any object (of any category)', could there be some truth to it?

Comment: It's not clear what it means for a well defined statement to "factor through" Yoneda. It is not the case that every well defined statement can be uniquely rephrased in terms of the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: If Yoneda explain the joke...

Comment: @IsAdisplayName what about "There is a proof of any statement in which Yoneda's Lemma cannot be omitted"...? But nvm, it's probably just silly X

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman Sorry to be pedantic but we would need to say: "there is a proof of every true statement..."

Not sure if this revised claim is true. But its certainly close enough to true for the joke to be funny :)

Comment: Haha thanks, no problem at all. Glad at least some found it entertaining ^^ (despite the 1 downvote :/)